# why doesn't server.connect() work when server.create() does?

Tags: .net, msmq, netmsmqbinding, streaminsight

In setting up a simple streaminsight app, I am running into the issue where server.create() works and server.connect() fails. I am not sure what could be a potential cause.

EDIT: Source code here: http://pastebin.com/XigdxXLd

My setup:

- private msmq where clients send data
- server reads this msmq using the input adapter and yields output to a text file

With the above setup, if I create an in-memory instance of streaminsight server (using `server.create("MyInstance")`, it consumes all the messages in the msmq and works fine (it takes about a minute before the app exits, since it likes to sit on server.dispose() call for a while).

If I switch to server.connect using the following:

```
Server.Connect(
new EndpointAddress(@"http://localhost/StreamInsight/MyInstance")
);
```

it only consumes one message of the msmq and the app never completes. The project times out after a minute on `application.Delete()` (where application is the MS.CEP.application).

Can someone please help me with what I could be doing wrong ?

Also, I tried opening the `StreamInsightHost.exe.config` file recently, but neither notepad nor Visual studio would let me open it. Not sure if this can influence anything, but I just thought I'll put it out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone lands up in the land of black voodoo magic, here is the potion that will sail you through:

Solution at: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/streaminsight/thread/6972a647-73b1-4fbf-9d85-c88b66304316?prof=required